# Turn Two Input Text Fields into One Jquery Range Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, range, textfield

I would like to take

```
     <form name='bid_range' action='".$action."' method='post'>
     <ul>

     <p><input type=text name=bid_from size=6 value='' /></p>        
     <li><input type=text name=bid_to size='6' value='' /></li>
     <input type='hidden' name='bid_next' value='".$TPL_next_bid_value."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='seller_id' value='0'>
     <input type='hidden' name='bid_type' value='range'>
     <input type='hidden' name='title' value='".$TPL_title_value."' >
     <input type='hidden' name='category' value='".$TPL_category_value."' >
     <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$TPL_id_value."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='t_remained_bids' value='".$remained_bids."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='auction_type' value='".$auction_type."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='form_type' value='".$type."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='f5_num' value='".$f5_num."'>
     <input type=submit id='subbutton'  name='subbutton' value='BID' class='button' style='width:70px;'>
     </ul>
     </form>
```

... And turn that code into

```
<p>
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</p>
```

For the purpose of a jquery range slider instead of two text fields.  Can someone help in how to go around doing this?  O, and I also have the usual jquery javascript, but I'm not sure if that is needed to configure.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Take a look at this. It is exactly what you need.

Comment: I know about that.  I already have the javascript and everything set up for the jquery. The page still doesn't display a range slider and the input text fields are still there.

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle or post your Javascript + HTML that isn't working?